# String Index Out Of Bounds Exception in ricorsive method

Tags: java

The program returns a string obtained interchanging character of two strings; i.e. 
string s1 = "aceg" string s2 = "hfdb" the result is "abcdefgh"(the two strings have always the same length;

well, I proceded in this way :

```
public class Eserc2 {

    public static String ricorsiveString(String s1, String s2) {

        if(s1.length() == 0 && s2.length() == 0) {
            return "";
        } else {

            char c = s1.charAt(0);
            char b = s2.charAt(s2.length()-1);

            String s = String.valueOf(c) ;
            String t = String.valueOf(b) ;
            String tot = s+t ;

            return tot + ricorsiveString(s1.substring(1),s2.substring(s2.length()));
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String a = "aceg";
        String b = "bdfh";
        ricorsiveString(a,b);

    }
}
```

the problem is that when i compile pc finds an exception :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1
    at java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:658)
    at eserc2.Eserc2.ricorsiveString(Eserc2.java:20)
    at eserc2.Eserc2.ricorsiveString(Eserc2.java:26)
    at eserc2.Eserc2.main(Eserc2.java:34)
```

Can you help me please???

Comment: Where are lines 20 and 26?

Comment: when you *run* not compile. just for future ref

Answer (score 1):

```
 if(s1.length() == 0 && s2.length() == 0) {
```

should be

```
 if(s1.length() == 0 || s2.length() == 0) {
```

Comment: your algorithm won't sort the letters either, based on your example. will simple pair the two together.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is if `s2` is empty but not `s1`:

```
if(s1.length() == 0 && s2.length() == 0)
```

will be false (`s1` is not empty), but this line:

```
s1.length() == 0 && s2.length() == 0
```

will try to access character at position -1.

Note: had you debugged your program step by step, you would have found the issue in less time than it took you to type your question!

Answer (score 1):

This line is not doing what you want (the s2.substring(s2.length()) call always gives you a string of length 0)

```
return tot + ricorsiveString(s1.substring(1),s2.substring(s2.length()))
```

It should be replaced with

```
return tot + ricorsiveString(s1.substring(1),s2.substring(0, s2.length() - 1));
```

As a design choice, you should also test that the passed strings match your precondition that they must be the same length.  Alternately, changing the && test to an || (as others have suggested) will make the code work on strings of different lengths.

Answer (score 0):

The condition you stated is incorrect it should be :

```
if(s1.length() == 0 || s2.length() == 0) {
```

because if any one of the variable length is zero the code should not execute.